# trying to add string to vector

Tags: c++, vector, token

I am trying to create a function that will read in a string that may contain letters, operators or number and place them into a vector. I am having such a hard time trying to figure out how to place multi digit numbers into one place in a vector. This is what i have. Any help would be appreciated

```
vector <string> getTokens (string token){   

    int a = (int) token.length();
    string temp;
    vector <string> numbers;

    char t; 

    for (int i =0; i <a; i++){

        t = token[i];

        if (isdigit(t)){ //should i be using a while loop?

            numbers.at(i).push_back(t);
            //seg fault here
        }

        else if (t=='+' || t=='-' || t=='/' || t=='*' || t=='^'){   
            cout << "operator" <<endl;
            string tt;
            tt+=t;
            numbers[i] = tt;
        }       


        else if (t=='(' || t==')'){
            string tt;
            tt += t;
            numbers[i] = tt;
        }
```

Comment: `numbers` is *empty*. Any indexing will be out of bounds. You should `push_back` the strings.

Comment: yes but what if the number is "123" ? it will push 1 , 2 , 3 right?

Comment: Put `numbers.resize(a)` before the loop starts, that's one way to do it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani what will that do?

Comment: Should I be using a while loop to check for string numbers?

Comment: @GraceFriedman `numbers.resize(a)` will, unsurprisingly, resize `numbers` so its length is `a`.

Comment: The reason your code crashes is that you are trying to access the 1st element of a vector that only has 0 elements.

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of your code I take it that you are writing a lexer / tokenizer.

One way of doing this is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector <std::string> getTokens (std::string token){   
        
        std::vector<std::string> numbers;
        std::string temp;
        
        //iterators to begin and end of input
        std::string::const_iterator iter = token.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = token.end();
        
        //keep looping until we have seen each character
        while(iter < end){
            //if is a digit
            if(std::isdigit(*iter)){
                //loop until the current char is no longer a digit
                while(std::isdigit(*iter)){
                    //collect the digit into temp
                    temp+=*iter;
                    //advacnce the iterator
                    ++iter;
                }
                //store the resulting string
                numbers.push_back(temp);
                //clear temp
                temp.clear();
            }
            //you could also check for other types of characters with else if(...) cases
            else{
                //discard all non numbers
                
             std::cout<<*iter<<" is not a number... discarding!"<<std::endl; 
             ++iter;//make sure to adavnce the iterator
            }
            
        }
        return numbers; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string input = "123a123";
    
    std::vector<std::string> out = getTokens(input);
    
    for(auto&& x: out){
     std::cout<<x<<std::endl;   
    }
    
}
```

Output:

> a is not a number... discarding!
>
> 123
>
> 123

[LIVE DEMO!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cb101e68f9790b7)

You are doing a few things that will cause issues with your code:

You are getting the segfault because `numbers` is empty when you call `at()` here:

```
numbers.at(i).push_back(t);
            //seg fault here
```

Let me know if you need further explanation of the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping! I finally got it.

```
for (int i =0; i <a; i++){

            t = token[i];
            if(isdigit(t)){
            string tt;
            while (isdigit(token[i])){
                tt+= token[i];              
                i++;                
            }
            numbers.push_back(tt);
        }
```

this takes care of the number issue at least